# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_ylim' after setting the limits for a seaborn scatterplot in python

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn

I am working in python and attempting to change the limits of a scatterplot. I have the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=[12, 11])
ax2a = sns.lmplot('LOC_X',
                 'LOC_Y',
                 data=curry_data,
                 fit_reg=False,
                 height=10,
                 aspect=2)


plt.title('Steph Curry shot attempt')
# Set x-axis label
plt.xlabel('LOC X')
# Set y-axis label
plt.ylabel('LOC Y')




# Set x/y limits and labels

ax2a.set(xlim=(-300,300),ylim=(-100,500))


plt.show()
```

I get this output, so visually the axis has been changed successfully.
[image]

However when trying to run the following code to verify that the ranges have been changed:

```
ax2a.axes.get_ylim()
ax2a.axes.get_xlim()
```

I get the following errors

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_ylim'
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_xlim'
```

From my understanding I successfully changed the limits however I am a bit confused on how to approach this for the Axes. I generally want to plot a scatterplot and change the Axes limits of the scatterplot. How can I do this so that upon running the last two lines of code I do not get an error and get the proper limits back? from my understanding the code I ran should have changed the axes.

Comment: Some how you've set `ax2a.axes` to be a numpy array, when it should be plotter `axes` object.  An array does not have plot methods like `get_ylim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `lmplot()`, which uses a `FacetGrid` to map "a dataset onto multiple axes arrayed in a grid of rows and columns that correspond to levels of variables in the dataset." (quoted [for the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid)).

The property `FacetGrid.axes` is always a 2D array of subplot `Axes`, even if the FacetGrid only has one plot. Therefore, to access the subplot, you need to run

`ax2a.axes[0,0].get_xlim()`

That being said, if you do not need to functionalities provided by a `FacetGrid`, you'd be better off using the simpler `sns.regplot()`, or `sns.scatterplot()` since you don't seem to be interested in the regression either. These functions act on the current Axes, and return an Axes object directly.

Comment: Okay but how can I set up a scatterplot so if I run ax2a.axes.get_xlim() it returns the limit.  Essentially I would like to change my scatterplot so that ax2a.axes.get_xlim() works and ax2a.axes.get_ylim() works as well

Comment: `ax2a = sns.scatterplot(...); ax2a.set_xlim(-300,300); ax2a.get_xlim()`

Comment: Thank you so much using the scatterplot function did the trick